# Why does my son's name come up on my icloud messages when I use my mac to send one?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am the only user signed up on my macbook.  My son's name comes up as the sender when I message someone via the mackbook.  Also, why aren't texts to my phone coming through on my macbook?
Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Answer (score 1):

More info **would** be helpful.

But assuming you are using the messages.app that comes with macOS.

Open messages, go to the messages menu and select preferences > Accounts.

It is likely that the account that messages is using is your son's. You can uncheck his account (or just delete it) and add yours. And by "yours" I mean the same account you use on your iPhone/iPad which is usually the email address associated with your AppleID.